# iOs simulators no longer log in to iCloud

Tags: ios, authentication, icloud, simulator

Can anyone help me?

Since this morning iOS simulators no longer log in to iCloud. it just keeps trying to log in I assume.

sim trying to log in...
While Apple system status states all is ok.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ASJ.png

Logging in on own devices still works
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxB8a.png

tried resetting simulator and no changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your account has 2FA activated (which is highly recommended), you currently can't use it in the iOS Simulator for iCloud.

So you either create a test Apple ID without 2FA or temporarily deactivate 2FA for your account.

Comment: Thx Epaga, The issue was solved when apple released the next version of Xcode